# GPath expression for finding all attribute values by name

Tags: xpath, groovy, gpath

Looking for GPath expression to get list of attribute values using the attribute name:

```
def xmltxt = """<reports>
    <report category="weather">sunny</report>
    <report category="sports">golf</report>
    <report category="business">
      <subreport category="deals">wallstreet</subreport>
    </report>
    <report>NA</report>
    <report category="life">gossip</report>
 </reports>"""
```

..when searching for all `category` attributes, I want to get back this, regardless of where `category` attributes exists in the document:

`[weather, sports, business, deals, life]`

...but all my attempts retrieve more than what I want, appears it's returning nodes that don't have `category` attributes; I can remove the empty elements from the list, but I'd like to know why this is happening.

`[, weather, sports, business, deals, , life]`

```
  def names = xml.'**'.findAll{
     it.@category        
  }.collect{
     it.@category
  }
```

Comment: It's happening because you're asking to collect categories, which will be null if there isn't a category. You're not asking it to filter based on the presence of categories, so you also collect the nulls.

Comment: I can filter based on element names in `findAll` using `it.name() == 'some_name'`, but what's the equivalent for attribute names? I've tried so many combinations I'm seeing pink elephants in my living room.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
def parsed = new XmlParser().parseText( xmltxt )
parsed.'**'*.attribute( 'category' ).findAll()
```

should do.

Here you go, with `XmlSlurper` solution:

```
def parsed = new XmlSlurper().parseText( xmltxt )
parsed.'**'*.attributes().findResults { it.category }
```

Comment: need `XmlSlurper` solution :-)

Comment: Good you asked, I was about to add that as an update to asnwer. See my update. @raffian

Comment: @raffian Minor modification to my update. `deals` was missing in the list earlier.

Comment: You are the man! It worked!...just curious, if `'**'*.attributes()` works, why not `'**'*.elements()` too?

Comment: Because [NodeChild](http://groovy.codehaus.org/api/groovy/util/slurpersupport/NodeChild.html) has no property named `elements()`.